# what is the problem with my ajax and php code?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

What is the problem with my ajax and php code? It always show cannot connect to mysql. My wamp server is already switch on, but why can't it run? I try my other code with connect mysql, it worked.

### Client Side:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<option value="1">oscar</option>
<option value="2">charles</option>
<option value="3">fathur</option>
</select>
</form>
<br />
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

### Server Side

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'user123');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("showuser", $con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '".$q."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Hometown</th>
<th>Job</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Age'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Hometown'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Job'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: It sounds like the error is in your PHP code so perhaps if you could post that code we could be more helpful.

Comment: Please post the content of getuser.php

Comment: As a general rule I like to exit php rather than use echo's for actual html.  I think it really allows cleaner code but that's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your error is server side, check your logic there.  Or if you want post your server side logic and we'll take a peep at it :)  What you have posted there looks fine, no immediate errors come to mind...

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use a framework like JQuery?
Why reinvent the wheel?

Have a look of how simple it is:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){
    $(this).addClass("done");
  }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/